# Fully assembled 40% keyboard

Tags: keyboards

I've been looking for a long time for an *assembled* 40% keyboard. I don't want to build it myself, as my eyesight is not good enough for soldering [SMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-mount_technology) components and is barely enough to solder [through-hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through-hole_technology) components.

I'd like something similar to this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

I need it to be rectilinear for things like emulating a [numeric keypad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad) or full navigation (arrows + <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd>), as I'll be using it primarily for programming.

@Romen comments that some kits don't need soldering at all. That would be very nice.

While not having it, I've seen the [Keychron C3 Pro](https://www.amazon.es/dp/B0CL9YZMFS/) that would allow me to learn how to use [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/faq_general?id=what-is-qmk)/[Via](https://docs.keeb.io/via) to program it for not much money.

What would you recommend?

Comment: What is the object?  Custom layout or just something to do?

Comment: FYI building a keyboard yourself doesn't have to involve soldering at all. **Lots** of DIY keyboard kits have hot swappable switch sockets where you just snap the switches into place.

Answer (score 1):

The [Keychron Q9](https://www.keychron.com/products/keychron-q9-qmk-custom-mechanical-keyboard) ($120 - $150) and [Idobao Abacus ID42](https://mechkeys.com/products/idobao-abacus-id42-40-hot-swap-mechanical-keyboard-kit?rfsn=7127324.e74ca8&variant=42908546203871) ($120 - $170) both come pre-assembled. They also both feature:

- Hot-swappable switches (no soldering required), with both barebones kits and included switch/keycap kits available wiht several switch types and keycaps
- Aluminum frames
- Programmability via QMK/VIA
- Per-key RGB lighting

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer a classic rectilinear design, but these are nice and worth considering. I didn't know any of the two.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there are any rectilinear designs that come pre-soldered. I'm sure you could just buy a kit of your choosing though and bring it to any local (or online) electronics shop and have them solder it for you though, there's several thru-hole only kits.

Comment: Yes, Q9 is 40%. Here is [a feature matrix for Keychron keyboards](https://www.keychron.com/blogs/news/difference-among-keychron-keyboards) (though it is somewhat incomplete). Q9 is the only 40% in it. The next size up is 60%.

Comment: Note that per-key RGB lighting, outside of RGB animation modes, is currently [only unlocked by custom C programming](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2023/10/02/setting-rgb-colour-for-individual-keys-in-qmk/) (though relatively simple as it is about using the existing "API"), not in any of the tools (at least not the mainstream ones; a hack might exist somewhere. Something like *[OpenRGB](https://lemmy.ml/c/openrgb)* probably requires very considerable effort to get going ([a demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MHtLEiXaXg) (e.g., from 29 min 13 secs))).

Comment: I believe VIA has a GUI that supports lighting controls, without the need to use the C API; it's not as pretty as some proprietary UIs, but it's there and I'd expect it to improve with time. [Here's Keychron's page on the matter](https://www.keychron.com/pages/how-to-program-the-backlight-keys-on-via).